# How to add the correct labels to a bubble chart without using VBA

Tags: excel, bubble-chart

I'm trying to make a bubble chart were categories is the label vector. However, I can't add the "categories" values as data labels or as legend components.How can I solve this issue?
Data ( products is the for size of bubble), Satisfaction is X and Price is Y

```
Categories  products    Satisfaction    Price
a            2158          59    23.85542169
b            207           61   30.82125604
c            193           61   47.48704663
d            49            55   17.44897959
e            30            59   23.66666667
f            152           48   23.98026316
g            59            71   32.88135593
h            12            71   16.66666667
i            30            73   20
j            29            63   33.44827586
k            69            79   31.23188406
l            27            81   27.40740741
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add data label to bubble chart in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669593/how-to-add-data-label-to-bubble-chart-in-excel)

Comment: as it says in the second answer in the linked question above...Without using VBA, right click on the bubbles and select Add Data Labels. Then, right click on the data labels and click Format Data Labels. Under Label Options, select Value From Cells and specify the cells containing the labels you'd like to use.

Comment: @R Hamilton , thanks but I don't have the "Value From Cells". My Excel version is 2010..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for those who have the same problem with old versions of Excel.
I used this free tool and it did the work.
(I have no connection to the tool or producer)
http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm